# Transferring ether from test account to contract in Remix

Tags: solidity, ether, remix

I have a contract successfully deployed and working well in the Javascript VM on Remix.

```
contract BlipCoinIco is PausableToken {
  *snip*

  function() isIcoOpen payable {
      totalRaised = totalRaised.add(msg.value);

      uint256 tokenAmount = calculateTokenAmount(msg.value);
      balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet].sub(tokenAmount);
      balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokenAmount);
      Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, tokenAmount);

      // immediately transfer ether to fundsWallet
      fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function calculateTokenAmount(uint256 weiAmount) constant returns(uint256) {
      // standard rate: 1 ETH : 50 ESP
      uint256 tokenAmount = weiAmount.mul(50);
      if (now <= startTimestamp + 7 days) {
          // +50% bonus during first week
          return tokenAmount.mul(150).div(100);
      } else {
          return tokenAmount;
      }
  }

  *snip*
}
```

The Javascript VM provides a couple of test accounts with preloaded Ether:

[image]

The contract owner and fund's wallet belongs to the first test account.

How can I send ether to the first test account, from the second test account, so that it hits the contract's `isIcoOpen` payable function?

I've tried using the `send` and `transfer` functions, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have to send ether to the other account to trigger the function.
The function you mention is a fallback function of the contract. To trigger it you have to send ether to the contract, not the accounts you list.

Comment: Right, I think I was just mixing up my terms, I understand. I have the contract address, how do I send ether from one of the test accounts to the contract so that it gives that account tokens? I have this contract working on the test net with MetaMask by the way, I just don't know how to transfer ether with these VM accounts.

Comment: You could execute the fallback function (in red in Remix when you compile the contract) and supply ether to it by setting the value.

Comment: Yep, just figured this out myself. Thanks! Setting the 'Value' in the 'Run' tab where the accounts are listed, then hitting the 'fallback' function sends ether to the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Setting and using a transfer function from your contract and then passing a value is one way. You can also send ether (if you've deployed your contract) by setting a value and using the low-level call.

[image: Set Value]

[image: Transact]